# Batch choice with time set

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make a batch file with arrow keys. The goal is to make it when a player does nothing in a selected time it will go to play. The problem is when I use timeout it wont let the player move until time =0 and when time = 0 you have to click any key to change it.

```
:arrow
timeout /t 5
choice /c:olws /n

if timeout == 0 goto play 

if %errorlevel%==1 goto o
if %errorlevel%==2 goto l
if %errorlevel%==3 goto w
if %errorlevel%==4 goto s

:o
set f%p%= 
set /a p=%p%-10
goto play
:l
set f%p%= 
set /a p=%p%+10
goto play

:w
set g%o%= 
set /a o=%o%-10
goto play
:s
set g%o%= 
set /a o=%o%+10
goto play
```

Comment: You can examine this script and ask for help at dostips regarding SNAKE.BAT - An arcade style game using pure batch http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4741

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the proper `choice` parameters: `/t` and `/d`

Comment: I  tried timeout /t 5 /d and it showed up as invalid.

Comment: did you define a default?  `choice /c:olws /n /t 5 /d o`

Comment: I go to this 
choice /c:olwsq /n /t 1 /d q that worked but is there a way to make q work faster.

Comment: A problem is that if I don't press q it will still act as if I did and do the other choice.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with ping localhost to make the time sorter.